# Service web hook - get artifacts of succeeded build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We're using Azure Pipelines to build our project. We configured a Service Hook for the Event "Build completed" and everything is working as planned.

However, we don't receive information about the build's artifacts. How to obtain a specific artifact from the build in the web hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the information about the build artifacts not passed in the Build Completed JSON.

What you can do it's after you catch the event make a Rest API call in your service to get the artifacts details according the build id (build id you of course got in the service hook json).

The Rest API to get artifacts details is [Artifacts - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/list).

Comment: Yea... it because you got something like the "Get Build" Rest API, and there also you don't get the artifacts info.